# ListView alternate row color is wrong when scrolling up und down fast

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

following problem: I use a custom ArrayAdapter and implement the ViewHolder pattern, when showing a list of items. I also use convertViews. 
On loading everything is fine and list items are shown in correct, alternating colors.

But when I scroll fast up and down, the colors change and are not alternating anymore... 
for Example when loading: green, blue, green, blue ... 
After scrollin: green, blue, green, green, green, green....

Here is some Code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewHolder holder;

    StoreTemplate curr = templates.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_store_rowlayout,
                parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.name);
        // more attr skipped here...
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(curr.getName());
    // more attr set here...


    // this changes background
    if ((position % 2) == 0) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.background_green));
    }


    // code skipped here

    return convertView;
}
```

How can I assure, that rows are ALWAYS colored altenately, even if I scroll, or search and reload the list?

Comment: I'd put an **else** branch that colors your **not even** rows in **blue**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting the `else` part of the `if statement` where you are changing row background. You might want to try like this:

```
// this changes background
    if ((position % 2) == 0) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.background_green));
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.your_color));
    }
```